# How to find a link in HTML document? (C#)

Tags: c#, html, xml, browser

I have a C# Form with WebBrowser object.
This object contains HTML Document.
And there is a link in that document that has no markers (no id and no name)
How can I access this element??

I tried to use this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[n]
```

But it is not very useful, because if there will be some new link on the page, I'll need to rebuild all program.

I also can not do loops through document, or get a substring of Document.ToString() because then I can not click the link.

Would be great if you could give me some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of situation the best idea is always to find an "Anchor", meaning - a place in the document that never change.

Lets say that

```html
<a href="http://site.com">dada</a>
```

Doesn't have an ID or Name, so the closest you can go is check if the parent of the element you're looking for has an ID.

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
      Some text
      Some other stuff
      <a href="http://site.com">The link you're looking for</a>
</div>
```

That way you could get the parentDiv, which you know doesn't change, and then the A tag inside that parent (which should be permanent unless that website completely changes the structure which is one of the problems in parsing external HTML pages)

Shai.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  Html Agility Pack. and select links by xpath

```
 HtmlWeb htmlWeb  = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load(/* url */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
   // do stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some info on how to identify the link. it may be id or name or the text. If the text is always same then check the inner text of that link.